# Installer for Microchip's 433.92 MHz Wireless Dev Board doesn't work

Tags: download, installation, microchip, mplab

I can't install the USB drivers for Microchip's Wireless Dev Board. The part number is "DM182017-1" for this kit.

I followed Microchip's instructions for downloading the USB driver, but the installer tool for USB provided doesn't work.

To see these instructions, Google the "MCS3142 Dual KeeLoq Encoder Wireless Remote Control Development Kit User's Guide" and scroll to section 8.2 in the PDF. This section provides several links for finding and downloading the installer tools.

The GUI downloads, both the KeyLoq encoder and decoder, downloaded just fine. For some reason, it was finicky about where it was downloaded. I fixed it by creating a folder on the desktop and changing the directory to that, but I don't know how that fixed anything.

I'm using a 64-bit Windows 7 OS, and am using the x64 installer tool that goes with that version. I created a ticket on Microchip's website, but they haven't gotten back to me yet. When I spoke to Microchip yesterday for a different issue, they admitted that this is a rather niche board.

There are a ton of files you need just to get started with this thing, and virtually no tutorials online beyond Microchip's documentation. Oh, and enjoy random freezing on your computer if you try to download the USB installer too many times. I had to restart my computer twice now.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. Looks like I didn't have admin privileges. Worked like a charm, and I can move on.